# Parametric solution of quartic diophantine equation in three variables

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, parametrization

> How can I handle the quartic diophantine equation in three variables $x$, $y$ and $z$ $$x^4-x^2=y^2-z^2$$ in general, i.e, does exists a (three-variable) parametric solution?

What I've tried is modifying Brahmagupta's identity, which yields a parametric solution to $x^2+y^2=u^2+v^2$

$$\left(ac-bd\right)^2 + \left(ad+bc\right)^2 = \left(ac+bd\right)^2 + \left(ad-bc\right)^2$$

Reorganizing, there are two options:

$$\left(ad+bc\right)^2 - \left(ad-bc\right)^2 = \left(ac+bd\right)^2 - \left(ac-bd\right)^2 \tag{1}$$

$$ \left(ad+bc\right)^2 -  \left(ac+bd\right)^2  = \left(ac+bd\right)^2 - \left(ad+bc\right)^2  \tag{2}$$

For $(1)$, we can simplify as $\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^2 - \left(\alpha-\beta\right)^2 = \left(\gamma+\delta\right)^2 - \left(\gamma-\delta\right)^2$. Looking at the left side, we try to get

$$ \alpha+\beta = x^2 \quad \quad \alpha-\beta=x$$
Then,
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{2}x(x + 1) \quad \quad \beta=\frac{1}{2} (x-1) x$$

By parity ($x$ or $(x + 1)$ is even, similar to $(x-1)$ and $x$ ), we can obtain the straightforward (but trivial) one-parameter solution(s)

$$a=\frac{n}{2} \quad d=n+1 \quad b=\frac{n}{2} \quad c=n-1$$

$$\left(n^2\right)^2 - \left(n\right)^2 = (n^2)^2-(n)^2$$

The results are similar if you move around the $\frac{1}{2}$ and the polynomial terms on the variables $a,b,c,d$ (example $a=\frac{n+1}{2}, d=n$).

For $(2)$, we have

$$\left(ad+bc\right)=x^2 \quad \quad \left(ac+bd\right)=x$$

but a continuation isn't clear. I've also tried finding solution tuples using a Python script, and the number of solutions is vast.

Comment: note that $x$   can be anything, as $x^4 - x^2$   is always divisible by $4.$ Call it $4k.$   One solution to $y^2 - z^2 = 4k$  has $y = k+1, \; \; z = k - 1.$ Typically there are more $y,z$  pairs, coming from factoring $4k = mn $   with both $m,n$ even

Comment: That explains the huge number of solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^4-x^2\equiv0\pmod{4}$ for all $x$. Factoring the right hand side as
$$x^4-x^2=(y+z)(y-z),\tag{1}$$
we have $y+z\equiv y-z\pmod{2}$, and so both are even. So this yields a factorization of $\frac{x^4-x^2}{4}$.

Conversely, for any factorization $\frac{x^4-x^2}{4}=uv$ we have a solution
$$(y,z)=\left(u+v,u-v\right),$$
to equation $(1)$. So you are looking for a parametrization of all factorizations of numbers of the form $\frac{x^4-x^2}{4}$.

One ad-hoc way to do so is to take any integer $x$ and any divisor $u$ of $\frac{x^4-x^2}{4}$, and set $v:=\frac{x^4-x^2}{4u}$, and set $y:=u+v$ and $z=u-v$. That is to say
$$\left\{\left(x,u+\frac{x^4-x^2}{4v},u-\frac{x^4-x^2}{4v}\right):\ u,x\in\Bbb{Z},\ u\text{ divides }\frac{x^4-x^2}{4}\right\}.$$